# What type should it be , after using .toArray() for a Spark vector?

Tags: python, numpy, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to transfer my vector to array, so I use

```
get_array = udf(lambda x: x.toArray(),ArrayType(DoubleType()))
result3 = result2.withColumn('list',get_array('features'))
result3.show()
```

where the column `features` is vector dtype.  But Spark tells me that

```
 net.razorvine.pickle.PickleException: expected zero arguments for construction of ClassDict (for numpy.core.multiarray._reconstruct)
```

I know the reason must be the type I use in the UDF so I tried `get_array = udf(lambda x: x.toArray(),ArrayType(FloatType()))`, which also cannot work.I know it is numpy.narray after transfer, but how can I show it correctly?

Here is the code how I get my dataframe result2:

```
df4 = indexed.groupBy('uuid').pivot('name').sum('fre')
df4 = df4.fillna(0)
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler 
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=df4.columns[1:],
    outputCol="features")
dataset = assembler.transform(df4)
bk = BisectingKMeans(k=8,  seed=2, featuresCol="features")
result2 = bk.fit(dataset).transform(dataset)
```

Here is what indexed looks like:

```
+------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+----+
|              uuid|    category|     code|   servertime|         cat|       fre|catIndex|name|
+------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+----+
|   351667085527886|         398|     null|1503084585000|         398|0.37951264|     2.0|  a2|
|   352279079643619|         403|     null|1503105476000|         403| 0.3938634|     3.0|  a3|
|   352279071621894|         398|     null|1503085396000|         398|0.38005984|     2.0|  a2|
|   357653074851887|         398|     null|1503085552000|         398| 0.3801652|     2.0|  a2|
|   354287077780760|         407|     null|1503085603000|         407|0.38019964|     5.0|  a5|
|0_8f394ebf3f67597c|         403|     null|1503084183000|         403|0.37924168|     3.0|  a3|
|   353528084062994|         403|     null|1503084234000|         403|0.37927604|     3.0|  a3|
|   356626072993852|   100000504|100000504|1503104781000|   100000504| 0.3933774|     0.0|  a0|
|   351667081062615|   100000448|      398|1503083901000|         398|0.37905172|     2.0|  a2|
|   354330089551058|1.00000444E8|     null|1503084004000|1.00000444E8|0.37912107|    34.0| a34|
+------------------+------------+---------+-------------+------------+----------+--------+----+
```

In `result2`, I have some columns with type `double`, and then I use `VectorAssembler` assemble those double columns into a vector `features`, which is the column that I want to transfer to array.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[NumPy types are not supported as the return values](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-12157) for the `UserDefinedFunctions`. You have to convert the output to standard Python `list`:

```
udf(lambda x: x.toArray().tolist(), ArrayType(DoubleType()))
```